# Alfresco 5.0.d - org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I am using OOTB alfresco 5.0.d with no modification in alfresco code.
After every 2-3 days after restart, the system starts throwing "CmisUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized" when trying to upload a document through we scripts but works fine from share interface.

StackTrace :
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:460)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:629)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.createFolder(ObjectServiceImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.createFolder(SessionImpl.java:814)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createFolder(FolderImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createFolder(FolderImpl.java:479)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The connection was automatically getting stale after that duration. Had to refresh the connection to solve this problem.